# Trying to parse some substrings in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell

I've been banging my ahead against the wall trying to do what should be a fairly simple substring search in Powershell.

I have a text file with the following content:

2015-08-30 13:12:59   10944512 DATACLUS1\RandomDBName_FULL_20150823_044919.bak
2015-08-30 13:12:59   11010048 DATACLUS1\RandomDBName_FULL_20150830_050126.bak

I need to pull out the filename(s) ("DATACLUS1\RandomDBName_FULL_20150823_044919.bak") and then compare to see which one was created later by the data stamp (20150823 in this case) and then output to a text file that contains only the full name to be actioned later in the process.

I've gone through regex's, match and substring but can't find a combination which will allow me to reliably pull that data. Once I'm over this hurdle I can move on to the compare.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so we can help?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without extensive regex if you want (assuming each line in the file is a newline.

```
# Fetch the lines of your backup file 
$lines = (Get-Content .\backup.data);
# Format the items in a proper way
$formattedItems = $lines|Select-Object @{Name="Filename"; Expression={($_ -split " ")[3]}}, @{Name="DataStamp"; Expression={(($_.Trim() -split " ")[-1] -split "_")[-2]}}, @{Name="TimeString"; Expression={(($_.Trim() -split " ")[-1] -split "_")[-1] -replace ".bak" ,""}};;    # Sort the items by the new property DateString
$sortedItems=$formattedItems|Sort-Object -Property DataStamp
```

This will give you a sorted list with properties on which you can select on (e.g 
you can use the first [0] of $sortedItems).

If you do not want to sort on DataStamp you could select the DateTime stamp (in the beginning of each line, which would probably be more reliable to sort on).